# fastest way to interact with a website in python

Tags: python, c++, selenium, python-requests, packets

I know we can use selenium with chrome driver as a high level website interaction tool, we can speed it up with Phantomjs. Then we can use the requests module to be even faster. But that's where my knowledge stops.

whats the fastest possible way in python that someone can do post and get requests? I assume there is a lower level library than requests? do we use sockets and packets?

'To execute the request as fast as possible'

if python's requests lib is the fastest is there other libs in other programming languages such as c++ that worth a look at?

It really depends on the task, for web scraping 1000 pages its fine but when you need to requests.post 1000000+ it adds up. I've also looked into the multiprocessing lib. It helps a lot using all computational resources I have but traversing the network and waiting for the response is the thing that takes the longest. I would have thought the best way to increase speed is by sending and receiving less data. lets say receive only 5 input parameters and send only those 5 as a post back and wait for a 200 response. any ideas how can i do this without receiving all source code?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "fastest"? Do you quick to code up, or quick to execute the request?

Comment: i mean execute as fast as possible

Comment: in Java you have the HttpURLConnection class which does low level calls to URLs. Then you can check response codes and parse the results.

Comment: The time spent preparing the request and parsing the reply on the computer will be negligible in relation to the the time spent traversing the network stack and the actual network.

Comment: I'm impressed that you can tell the difference between 900 and 850 millisecond response time. Darn. those 50 milliseconds sure take a long time to tick by.

Comment: It really depends on the task, for web scraping 1000 pages its fine but when you need to requests.post 1000000+ it adds up. I've also looked into the multiprocessing lib. It helps a lot using all computational resources I have but yes traversing the network and waiting for the response is the thing that takes the longest. I would have thought the best way to increase speed is by sending and receiving less data. lets say receive only 5 input parameters and send only those 5 as a post back and wait for a 200 response. any ideas how can i do this without receiving all source code?

Comment: Have you looked into asynchronous requests?

Comment: @JETM no I haven't, ill have a look thanks! :D